# Directly connecting two computer also on same LAN

Tags: networking

This might be a weird one, which is probably why I couldn't find anything on searches.

I have two machines on the same network connected to the same switch via Gigabit Ethernet. One is my main workstation, running Windows 10, the other is my server, running Windows Server 2016. These two machines are within a few feet of each other and I'd like to get a better transfer rate between the two. Ideally I'd like a 10G link between the two, but one of the machines (the server) has no more room for internal expansion (and no thunderbolt). My plan is to fit that one with a USB 3.1 Gen 2 5Gb Ethernet adapter, and the other with an internal PCIe 10Gb Ethernet adapter. I then want to directly connect the two, while also leaving in place the current 1Gb network connections to the main network/internet. None of the other machines on the network need a faster link, so upgrading the infrastructure isn't practical.

So my question before I do all this... when I go to copy files between the two machines, is Windows smart enough to use the faster link, or is it going to be dumb and go through the network switch on the 1Gb connection? If it's dumb, can I override this with a hosts file for the static IP4/IP6 addresses on each computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to change the windows metric for any network adapter.  Lower metric=higher priority.  Using a metric from 6-9 should be low enough without messing anything else up.

Comment: Are you saying I can essentially tell Windows to prioritize one NIC and always use that, unless the resource it's looking for isn't there then use the other? Would that cause any latency as it tries to connect to any resource not on the main (5Gb) NIC?

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, computer W (workstation) is connected to the switch via a 1Gbps link, and to computer S (server) via a 5Gbps link (crossover cable?), while computer S is also connected to the switch via a 1Gbps link.

I suggest you configure two networks so that the 1Gbps interfaces on the server and workstation are on one network (e.g. 192.168.0.0/24), and the high speed interfaces are on another network (e.g. 10.0.0.0/24).

When you want to use the high speed connection, simply refer to the remote host by the IP address on the high speed link.  It is a directly connected network so routing and link metrics shouldn't come into play.

Comment: I don't actually have the second NIC yet, they are only connect via a 1Gb switch right now... I'm trying to figure out if it's feasible to do what I want first before buying any new equipment.

Comment: Having a second NIC would already give another IP address, but there are applications which I cannot hardcode a reference to an IP, it autodetects the domain controller and connects that way. Another application will only reference by hostname.

Comment: There is nothing preventing you from establishing a second hostname for the second IP address.  I know less about AD domains, so you might be on your own there.

Comment: Also, are your disks on both sides faster than the 1Gbps link you have between machines?  Because if they are not (e.g. rotational disks @ 35MB/s), then you won't get any benefit from the faster network link for copying files (your example), and it wouldn't make sense to spend the money.

Comment: Yes, the workstation has PCIe SSDs, while the server has a 72TB RAID volume which DiskMark says can do about 700 MB/s

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Latency would only be an issue once while binding, and I doubt any human would notice.  If the adapter referenced with the lower metric is unavailable then windows just moves on to the next until it becomes available again.